# remove post html, js, css on insert into mysql

Tags: php, mysql

When I post `html`, `js`, `css` tag, rule, syntax's on text input. it show's up on page result!
I user `$conn->real_escape_string` and `mysqli prepared statement` but still not secure for me.
**my code is**:

```
<?php
   require 'config/config.php';
   mysqli_set_charset($conn,"utf8");
$qmsg = $_POST["qsmsg"];
$qmsgs = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $qmsg);
$ansr = "Answer";
$userName = "John";
$userId="4";
$userType="user";
$imgsp="images/avatar.jpg";

$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO qa (qus, ansrq, uname, uid, utype, uimage) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("sssiss", $qmsgs, $ansr, $userName, $userId, $userType, $imgsp);
...
$stmt->close();
$conn->close();
?>
```

**Result on my page:**
[image]

Comment: You're using placeholder values, which is great, but you're also escaping, which is a mistake: That double-escapes things and damages data. Only use placeholder values and `bind_param`.

Comment: @tadman could you explain your comment by using code for me, please.

Comment: Remove the line with `mysqli_real_escape_string`, it doesn't belong and it's going to wreck your data.

Comment: @tadman something like this: `$qmsgs = $qmsg;` ?

Comment: That just creates a variable that's a copy of another, so that's redundant. Just pass `$qmsg` into `bind_param` and you're good to go.

Comment: $qmsg = htmlspecialchars($_POST["qsmsg"]);

Comment: @tadman this also work: `$qmsgs = htmlspecialchars(mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["qsmsg"]));` ? or bad idea ?

Comment: Don't pre-escape, you have no idea where that data is going to end up. What if you update your application to send that over JSON? Then you need to de-escape it, then re-escape it for JSON. That's super messy. General rule: Escape it *only* when you're displaying it, not saving it.

Comment: You're right. thank you

Comment: @Tony no, that's a bad idea. See [Using htmlspecialchars function with PDO prepare and execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38411112/using-htmlspecialchars-function-with-pdo-prepare-and-execute)

Comment: @Phil I'm not using PDO, I'm using MySqli.

Comment: @SchoolforDesign read past the specifics. _"Filter input / escape output"_ is a general idea and not one tied to any particular technology.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an XSS problem, not a database or CSS problem.

The quick answer is you **must** call [`htmlspecialchars`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) on any user data that you're displaying in an HTML context. That will neutralize any HTML a user's introduced either deliberately or by accident.

The long answer is people like to be able to put in some formatting, so consider using something like [Markdown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) so you can type things like `*bold*` and `_italic_` and not have to write actual HTML. There are many, many PHP implementations of this readily available.